# How to retrieve Object class from jdk

Tags: java

As every class extends object class and executes its default constructor ,i was wondering if is there any way to see what this object class looks like and where it exists.

Comment: Not every class has a default constructor.  Further, where the class "exists" as it were is given by the package structure.

Comment: @makoto i mean here only object class

Comment: Have a look at the [sources](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Object.java.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JDK is developed as [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/). The sourc code is available as a Mercurial repository. `Object` is at

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/9bb0496deeb0/src/share/classes/java/lang/Object.java

You can also use your IDE to view the source code of every class that is shipped with source code.

Comment: i downloaded this ,i which folder i can get object.class file?

Comment: The `.class` files are in `rt.jar`.

Comment: and where is this rt.jar

Comment: In your JDK. Take a look, yo'll find it.